# GDB command to print full exception info for segmentation faults? 

Tags: gdb, x86

I'm debugging an optimized Linux executable under GDB. Our program crashes with a segmentation fault. However the faulting instruction doesn't seem to actually access an invalid pointer; it is basically a `mov 0xf00(%ebx), eax` op where 0xf00(%ebx) is valid memory. At least, it shows up when we `x` its address.

What is the GDB command to view *all* details on the currently caught exception, including the exact memory address that the faulting opcode tried to access? This info ought to be in the exception trap frame but I don't know how to get at that via GDB.

This is for x86 under Ubuntu.

Comment: The crash itself turned out to be a misaligned SIMD read; the address was valid but not aligned.

Answer (score 4):

> However the faulting instruction doesn't seem to actually access an invalid pointer; it is basically a mov 0xf00(%ebx), eax op where 0xf00(%ebx) is valid memory. At least, it shows up when we x its address.

I will guess that the address is in fact not valid (`mmap`ed with `PROT_NONE`).

The reason GDB can examine it is that on Linux, `ptrace` (which GDB uses to access inferior memory) will happily read from such addresses, while the application itself could not.

> What is the GDB command to view all details on the currently caught exception

Try `print $_siginfo` when GDB stops with the signal. Documentation [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Vars.html).